# Remove cast from a generic that extends from unknown

Tags: reactjs, typescript

From the component I have a generic that extends from unknow. This generic can be undefined but after the last checks it should be a value other than undefined.

If I don't cast this

```
return <>{render(data as NonNullable<T>)}</>;
```

typescript it gives me the following error: Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NonNullable'.
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'NonNullable'

Can the cast be somehow removed?

```
interface Props<T> {
  data: T;
  error: unknown;
  isLoading: boolean;
  render: (successData: NonNullable<T>) => void;
}

export const AsyncComponent = <T extends unknown>({
  data,
  error,
  isLoading,
  render,
}: Props<T>) => {
  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>loading</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  if (error) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>error</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  if (
    ((typeof data !== 'boolean' || typeof data !== 'number') && !data) ||
    (Array.isArray(data) && !data.length) ||
    (typeof data === 'object' &&
      data !== null &&
      !Object.keys(data as { [key: string]: unknown }).length)
  ) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>no results</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return <>{render(data as NonNullable<T>)}</>;
};
```

Comment: This will automatically fix itself when TypeScript 4.8 is released, with [improved support for narrowing `unknown`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-8-beta/#improved-intersection-reduction-union-compatibility-and-narrowing), specifically due to [ms/TS#49330](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/49330).  See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mpnGXw).  Does that address your question fully? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TypeScript 4.7 and below this is a limitation.  The compiler would treat [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown) as essentially a single monolithic type instead of a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all possible types.  And so a value of type `T extends unknown` would stay of type `T` when checked for being nullable.

TypeScript 4.8 will feature [improved support for narrowing `unknown` and generic types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-8-beta/#improved-intersection-reduction-union-compatibility-and-narrowing), including automatically narrowing a value of generic type `T` to one of type `NonNullable<T>` if checked for nullability. See [microsoft/TypeScript#49330](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/49330) for more information.

So as soon as TypeScript 4.8 is released, your example code will compile without the need for a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) (what you're calling a "cast").  You can test now with the beta or nightly TypeScript releases to verify.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-dev.20220706#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgAUcwBnAHgBUA+OAG9ycUXAAmKGCgBccHhTFx6OKHICu1ANbUIAd2qKxwDgBkIKcTQDmcgEYQIAG1SGRYotXH05ACg7qaGhIHBwAIlKycAByENTR6k5OKHYuvHwAlHAAvAIAbhDA4hQAvpRIAB6QsHBocRzwAIIcAJ7UaADCuJDUSLQ5cLzKFXReHHCaOvrUfL7CSpLSADTuoirQK0om5pY2mx593lArJXJsEJzpWblCq3DAmHC+2xZW1NZZ80oHMOpQ1E87t8xFwrHk+EDgd8uGA+E5XjYuAB6WGQ4HIsEQqFwDJGURlO4PJ7rKCfNFwIi-f6A7FKUHAcHk7Ewvgk5Go2kgpGY8m4u4EraPXzk3y+GAtMBICCPRYoOAAQmy2QIDmcrnwcAAPpq4OLJdKJJEFUqCNR1CA7PR8FkAGQ2hWyrLakWNKBQFAtAB0Jld7pavkdcDtDsinpc7xgAAsnZqRXqpTKjUrlfgIHYAFZIEhBm1MsSy43Ks1JHN50TygDyGazME9WiQLQ4AaNKHGgjgAG16y05A0oDYALoabS6AxwEoZMN9axRjJ3MnYyl-AHCzmiemMtfQ2G6CkhRIwbgorFrjEMk-AvlKMoLI1IpExOIJJIpNL8O5L6lcPiCTxHZvSBkJTInwpSkEAA)